# Convergence of function (elementary)

Tags: convergence-divergence

For what values of $a$ does the function $f(x) = x^a e^{-x}$ converge as $x \rightarrow 0$? It turns out that the answer is $a<-1$ but I don't understand how to arrive at the answer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as $e^{-x}$ tends to $1$, you have to have convergence of $x^a$, meaning simply $a\geq0$. Or you must have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Does that mean $\int_0^1x^a e^{-x}dx$ also converge for all $a \geq 0$?

Comment: Ah, now I get what the question is about! The answer is yes, although think carefully about what you're saying. If the function converges, then $0$ is not an improper bound and you're just integrating a continuous function over a segment. The converse is not true, the fact that that integral converges does not imply that $a\geq0$. Think of this: what is $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x} dx$ equal to, and why?